# JavaScript Arrays delete duplicate words or characters(if only characters are entered. Not to delete from 1 word all duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, continue

Enter : Samsung , Enter again : Samsung , Enter again: Tomas, Enter again: sass, Enter again : sass, Enter again: b, Enter again : b, Enter again : bb, Enter again : bb........

And to display the following : 
With removeDuplicateUsingSet: Samsung, Tomas, sass, b, bb
Without the function : Samsung,Samsung,Tomas,sass,sass,b,b,bb,bb
and the loop to stop when you type stop.....

```
function removeDuplicateUsingSet(arr){
let unique_array = Array.from(new Set(arr))
return unique_array}

var inputs =[];
var alreadyEntered = false;
while (!alreadyEntered) 
{
var input = prompt("Enter items until you enter it twice");

for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
    if (inputs[i] == input)
     {
        alert("Already entered!");
        alreadyEntered = true;
        break;
    }

}
inputs.push(input);
}



alert("With removeDuplicateUsingSet function : " + "\n" + 
removeDuplicateUsingSet(inputs) + "\n" + "Without: " + "\n" + inputs);
```

Now this code have break loop and i don't know how to fix it....
Tried doing this next thing :

```
function removeDuplicateUsingSet(arr){
let unique_array = Array.from(new Set(arr))
return unique_array
}

var array = [];
var stored = [];
while(array !== 'stop')
{
stored.push(prompt('what are your fav books ? '));
array = prompt('If you would like to continue enter any key otherwise enter or type stop');

// document.write(stored + " , ");
console.log(removeDuplicateUsingSet(array) + "\n___________");
}
alert("With removeDuplicateUsingSet function : " + "\n" + 
removeDuplicateUsingSet(array) + "\n" + "Without: " + "\n" + stored);
```

but also not what i have been wanted....
It keeps removing all of the duplicate characters (ex. "Samsung" displays it SAMUNG,where i want to remove if there are entered 2 same elements(items)
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your desired output?

```js
function removeDuplicateUsingSet(arr) {
  let unique_array = Array.from(new Set(arr))
  return unique_array
}

var inputs = [];
while (true) {
  var input = prompt("Enter items until you enter it twice");
  if (input == 'stop') break;

  inputs.push(input);
}

alert("With removeDuplicateUsingSet function : " + "\n" + removeDuplicateUsingSet(inputs) +
  "\n" + "Without: " + "\n" + inputs);
```

Comment: Yup :) i`ll compare and see what i did wrong :D huge thanks <3 ---.... omg i see now that i was using while instead of if .... :)

Comment: you still have to use while for user inputs. What you did wrong is: as user inputs, you tried to compare the array immediately. You already have the function to remove duplicates so all you have to do is just push the input into the array.

Comment: yeah i know now :D i have skipped some classes when i was in college and now im paying for them :D but luckily i`m at learning academy now and the teacher also explained what i have done wrong :D so thanks for the support and the quick answer, you kinda saved me there, and then i had the opportunity to learn what was right and what was wrong :D its much easier to see when you compare fully functional code with the one i`ve created :D